# Instantiating doubly inherited object properly?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to use double inheritance, to declare a more complex object, as the sum of two simpler ones. However when I try to do it as follows:

```
class common_cfullr
{
public:
  double core;
  double thr;
  double thrres;
  common_cfullr(double Core, double Thr, double Thrres){
    core=Core;
    thr=Thr;
    thrres=Thrres;
  };
  ~common_cfullr(){};
  common_cfullr() :
    core(0.0),
    thr(0.0),
    thrres(0.0)
  {}
};

class common_cfull
{
 public:
  int nelec;
  int ms2;

  common_cfull (int  Nelec,
  int  Ms2){
    nelec      =Nelec;  
    ms2        =Ms2;    
   };
  ~common_cfull(){};
  common_cfull() :
    nelec(0),
    ms2(0){}
};

///Structure inheritance
class  common :
  public common_cfullr,
  public common_cfull
{public:
  common(){};
  ~common(){};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  common cmn();
  cmn.nelec=0;

  return 0;
}
```

I get an error from the compiler. How can I use doubly inheritance properly, for this purposes?

Any sugestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you get an error, it would be nice of you to share what it said!

Comment: `common cmn();` this is the most vexing parse (google it). You must use `common cmn;`

Comment: It's actually not the most vexing parse, but it's related. This is a common misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Based on Neik Kirk's comment.) Changing `common cmn();` to `common cmn;` makes your code compile without an error.

When compiling with `clang++`, the *note* emitted by the compiler also tells you this:

```
t.cc:48:13: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration
      [-Wvexing-parse]
  common cmn();
            ^~
t.cc:48:13: note: remove parentheses to declare a variable
  common cmn();
            ^~
```